# DevExpress Hidden GridView CSS Issues

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, devexpress, repeater

I have a repeater control that repeats a DevExpress ASPxGridView for every item bound to the repeater.  The repeater is contained within an update panel. Events on the page, outside of the UpdatePanel, trigger the UpdatePanel (and subsequently the repeater) to update. All works fine if records are present to bind to the repeater.  The repeater renders a grid for each record and all styles look perfect.

If the page initially loads and there are no items to display in the repeater, no grids are rendered (works as intended up until this point).  If a record is eventually added and the repeater rebinds (because of the triggered UpdatePanel), the grid styles don't display.  If the entire page is refreshed, the grid's styles display perfectly.  Keep in mind that I'm using one of the default styles that comes with the grid, so these are being pulled from an AXD and not included in my MasterPage.

A bit too much code to post, but the nuts of the markup looks similar to this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="the UpdatePanelInQuestion" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
  <asp:Repeater ID="theRepeaterInQuestion" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="theMethodThatHandlesGridPopulation">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <dxwgv:ASPxGridView ID="theGridViewInQuestion" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
        <Columns>
        ...
        </Columns>
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Any ideas on how to make the styles of the grid display correctly without:
1) Refreshing the entire page instead of triggering.
2) Placing another empty grid on the page with style="display: none;" to force the styles to download.

Comment: Try to change UpdatePanel to ASPxCallbackPanel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is caused by the fact that the required scripts for the DX ASP.NET controls are not registered on the page initially. It is possible to register them explicitely via the **DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxWebControl.RegisterBaseScript** method.

Please check the http://www.devexpress.com/issue=B191046 Support Center ticket regarding this.

Comment: Haven't actually tried this, since I replaced the DevExpress grid with a Telerik RadGrid and didn't need to register the controls explicitly... but this is exactly what I was originally looking for.  Great find for future use!

Comment: Thank you for the comment. What can you say about Telerik RadGrid? I have not used it yet in my development.